# how to allow only certain people to push to ".github/wokflows" directory in github for all branches

Tags: github, github-actions, githooks

I came across an issue with working GitHub actions,
I have  built multiple central workflows for the ci-cd process and called this workflow in application repositories and building apps but some of the developers writing their own workflows to build applications and not following certain standards, so to make them use only central workflows I need to restrict any push to ".github/workflows" and allow only specified people to push to ".github/workflows"

Comment: You create a workflow that would me mandatory to merge PR and that would trigger only when the `.github/workflows` path is updated, with a condition checking the `github.actor` context variable to see if the author is from a specific list of allowed user. If not, the workflow should fail. [This action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/close-pull-request) can also help you achieve that.

Comment: Developers using their own workflows leaving my central workflows to skip sonar coverage, twist-lock scan to restrict them fro m doing this,
I want only specific people to push or commit code to the ".github/workflows " folder by restricting others

Answer (score 0):

since this is github-specific I'll give a github-specific answer:

1. set up [`CODEOWNERS`](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/customizing-your-repository/about-code-owners) for those files

   ```
   .github/ @your-team
   ```
2. enable [branch protection](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/about-protected-branches) for the branches you want

   - make sure to check **Require a pull request before merging**
   - then check **Require review from Code Owners**

Comment: Adding a CODEOWNERS file won't work for me because Developers can edit this CODEOWNERS file as well right?

i want only specific people to push or commit code to the ".github/workflows " folder

Comment: Developers using their own workflows leaving my central workflows to skip sonar coverage, twist-lock scan to restrict them fro m doing this, I want only specific people to push or commit code to the ".github/workflows " folder by restricting others

Comment: the CODEOWNERS file sits in `.github` -- so you'd be the owner of that as well

Comment: doing this is affecting all other folders as well with this should work only for the ".github" folder

Comment: use more words, you haven't communicated what's happening that's undesirable

Comment: I have followed the steps you have given as it is but it should work only for the ".github" folder right it is asking for the rest of the folders as well for CODEOWNERS review.